# How to update umbrella header using the podspec file?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

I want to add a few lines of code in the podspec file which will automatically update the umbrella header file on running pod install command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.